# Not showing the Android Pay payment sheet with continue button tap

Tags: android, android-pay

I have added Android Pay payment method in the app as part of checkout using Braintree. The debug build will show the Android Pay payment sheet with a continue button every time I click the 'Buy with android pay' button. But the signed build is not showing the payment sheet and it is loading the default address from android pay.

I need to show the payment sheet every time the 'Buy with android pay' is clicked.

Comment: can it be that you need to provide two different keys for debug/release to android pay ?

Comment: In the debug build the payment sheet is showing "Unrecognised app. Please make sure that you trust the app before proceeding". Each time the message will be shown along with the payment sheet.
In the release build the app is fetching the details with out showing the payment details.

Comment: Taken from the doc: "In addition, you need to generate a client id for production, sign your app with the release key, and target your environment to production." https://developers.google.com/android-pay/get-started

Comment: Have you done this ?

Comment: I'm using the Braintree integration. The release build is pointed to the production environment and are able to fetch the card details. But I want to see the payment sheet on clicking the 'Buy with android pay' button instead of fetching the default card details.

Comment: At last I got the reason. There is an option below the payment sheet to select the checkbox if we want to use the same card for future. This is checked initially and it wont show the payment sheet further.

Answer (score 0):

After you tap the Buy with Android Pay button, the Android Pay chooser pops up[payment sheet] allowing the user to choose their card and shipping address if required.

- when the **preauthorization** is enabled for the return users[second time users] the Android Pay chooser is skipped because the checkbox saying " use selected info for future purchases from the app" is checked before.  If your buyflow want to display the Android Pay chooser every time the Buy with Android dPay " is tapped you need to disable the preauthorization.

Either you must not register for [preauthorization](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/preauth) or reach out to [Android Pay support](https://support.google.com//androidpay/merchant/contact/android_pay).